# How can i bind object to value of ngx-typehead?

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

i have this array:

```
let cityArrays = [
  {
    "zip": "60645",
    "city": "Chicago / IL",
    "longitude": "42.008956",
    "latitude": "-87.69634"
  },
  {
    "zip": "60647",
    "city": "Chicago / IL",
    "longitude": "41.921126",
    "latitude": "-87.70085"
  },
}
```

How can i show all of the cities in the typehead,but when the value is selected one city, then to get the whole object on typeaheadOnSelect event

```
<input [(ngModel)]="selectedObject" [typeahead]="cityArrays"  [isAnimated]="true" class="form-control" (typeaheadOnSelect)="select($event)">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [specification](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-typeahead), this is what you need to do:

```
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="type a value from the list below"
      ngxTypeahead
      class="col-sm-12 form-control"
      [taList]="cityArrays"
      [taListItemField]="['city']"
      taListItemLabel="city"
      (taSelected)="handleStaticResultSelected($event)"
    />
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-typeahead-74a6ls?file=src/app/lists/static-list.ts) is a stackblitz demo of what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks.I didn't know for this library !

Comment: Just why when i choose some option in the typehead on the stackblitz demo, i get alert with the selected object but the option is not fully writed in the typehead it self ?